# Archiva failure, Workspace inconsistency error on node

Tags: apache, tomcat6, archiva

I am having an issue starting Archiva; the application starts but throws an error: `Workspace inconsistency error on node`. I am new to Archiva however so forgive my ignorance; specifically if this is miscategorized. The version appears to be `Archiva 2.2.0`; this is running on an `Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS` server. One factor that may have contributed to this is that this server, a VM, is a migrated server; we recently migrated it from a physical server; however I do not recall any issues when orginally testing this. I have provided the error. Please let me know if there is more information including I can provide. Any help in troubleshooting this is greatly appreciated!

Here is the error (truncated for readability):

> 2020-09-28 12:43:50,615 [WrapperSimpleAppMain] ERROR org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.OnWorkspaceInconsistency [] - Workspace inconsistency error on node /repositories/internal/facets/org.apache.archiva.metadata.repository.stats/2016/03/31 (5b8a0673-26cc-4e4a-8318-1d6438059de2) with child 31 (e105d1e9-c3aa-45e1-bdb5-ca2be2298eb2).
> org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.ItemStateException: failed to read bundle: e105d1e9-c3aa-45e1-bdb5-ca2be2298eb2: java.io.EOFException
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.BundleFsPersistenceManager.loadBundle(BundleFsPersistenceManager.java:249) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.AbstractBundlePersistenceManager.getBundleCacheMiss(AbstractBundlePersistenceManager.java:769) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.AbstractBundlePersistenceManager.getBundle(AbstractBundlePersistenceManager.java:752) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.AbstractBundlePersistenceManager.load(AbstractBundlePersistenceManager.java:490) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.SharedItemStateManager.loadItemState(SharedItemStateManager.java:1869) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.SharedItemStateManager.getNonVirtualItemState(SharedItemStateManager.java:1789) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.SharedItemStateManager.getItemState(SharedItemStateManager.java:270) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.MultiIndex.createIndex(MultiIndex.java:1232) [jackrabbit-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.MultiIndex.createIndex(MultiIndex.java:1242) [jackrabbit-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.MultiIndex.createIndex(MultiIndex.java:1242) [jackrabbit-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.MultiIndex.createIndex(MultiIndex.java:1242) [jackrabbit-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.MultiIndex.createIndex(MultiIndex.java:1242) [jackrabbit-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.MultiIndex.createIndex(MultiIndex.java:1242) [jackrabbit-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.MultiIndex.createIndex(MultiIndex.java:1242) [jackrabbit-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.MultiIndex.createInitialIndex(MultiIndex.java:386) [jackrabbit-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex.doInit(SearchIndex.java:574) [jackrabbit-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.AbstractQueryHandler.init(AbstractQueryHandler.java:78) [jackrabbit-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.RepositoryConfigurationParser$1.getQueryHandler(RepositoryConfigurationParser.java:683) [jackrabbit-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.WorkspaceConfig.getQueryHandler(WorkspaceConfig.java:251) [jackrabbit-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.SearchManager.(SearchManager.java:171) [jackrabbit-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl$WorkspaceInfo.getSearchManager(RepositoryImpl.java:1895) [jackrabbit-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl$WorkspaceInfo.doPostInitialize(RepositoryImpl.java:2134) [jackrabbit-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl$WorkspaceInfo.initialize(RepositoryImpl.java:2037) [jackrabbit-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.initStartupWorkspaces(RepositoryImpl.java:543) [jackrabbit-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.(RepositoryImpl.java:326) [jackrabbit-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [?:1.7.0_79]
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [?:1.7.0_79]
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [?:1.7.0_79]
> at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147) [spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122) [spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:267) [spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]